# I cant restore the dumpfile,

Tags: oracle11g, database-restore

i am useing Oracle 11g Express and i used this command to restore a dumpfile

```
impdp SCHEMAS=datamining DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir DUMPFILE=dm.dmp remap_tablespace=system:users
```

then it gave me the below error:

```
.
.
.
x number;
y varchar2(200);
l_input         utl_file.file_type;
begin
  dbms_output.enable;
  dbms_output.put_line(year_);
  dbms_output.put_line(cycle);
  select count(0) into x f
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
ORA-39083: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION failed to create with error:
ORA-31625: Schema DATAMINING is needed to import this object, but is unaccessible
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 6720
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Failing sql is:

ALTER FUNCTION "DATAMINING"."AUTO_CORR"   COMPILE         PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL=  2
  PLSQL_CODE_TYPE=  INTERPRETED    PLSQL_DEBUG=  FALSE    PLSCOPE_SETTINGS=  'ID
ENTIFIERS:NONE' REUSE SETTINGS TIMESTAMP '2015-10-02 10:04:21'
ORA-39083: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION failed to create with error:
ORA-31625: Schema DATAMINING is needed to import this object, but is     unaccessible
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 6720
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Failing sql is:

.
.
.
.
  CREATE  FORCE VIEW "DATAMINING"."B_CLEANING_1" ("FILE_", "CUSTOMER_ID", "PRE_DEB
T", "PRICE", "DATE_", "CYCLE_", "YEAR_") AS select     b."FILE_",b."CUSTOMER_ID",b."
PRE_DEBT",b."PRICE",b."DATE_",b."CYCLE_",b."YEAR_"
  from bills b
  where b.c
ORA-39083: Object type VIEW failed to create with error:
ORA-31625: Schema DATAMINING is needed to import this object, but is unaccessible
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 6720
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE  FORCE VIEW "DATAMINING"."MT" ("FILE_", "CUSTOMER_ID", "SPECIAL_TYPE", "U
SAGE1", "USAGE2", "USAGE3", "CYCLE_", "YEAR_", "END_", "LENGTH_DAY", "CONTRACT_P
OWER", "PRE_DEBT", "PRICE", "C_CYCLE", "B_DATE", "B_CYCLLE") AS select     m.file
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TYPE/TYPE_BODY
ORA-39083: Object type TYPE_BODY failed to create with error:
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE TYPE BODY "DATAMINING"."AUTO_CORRIMPL" IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT auto_corrImpl)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
-- initialize the variables
  BEGIN
sctx := auto_corrImpl(0, sys.odcinumberlist());
RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self  IN OUT auto_corrImpl,
                                   VALUE IN NUMBER) RETURN NU
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" completed with 69 error(s) at 06:29:50
```

comment 1:we did remap_tablespace because we wrongly put the schema on system tablespace,
comment 2:we run this code on one computer and it worked but it is not working on other computer
Please guide me...

Comment: Based on the error messages, does the schema exist?  If not, can you create it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the datamining user does not exist. Please create it and retry the import.

Thanks

Sabiha